# Using Google places Api in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a new rails app and I need to use Google places API but I don't know the steps to do that or the best way to use this API.
I have tried to search in developers.google.com I found the places API but I couldn't find how to use it in a rails app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just had to google it. You could have have found tons of stuff. Anyways here are a few gems that could help you

1. [Google Places](https://github.com/marceldegraaf/google_places)
2. [Google Places Autocomplete](https://github.com/fred/google_places_autocomplete)
3. [Gmaps](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/gmaps-autocomplete-rails)

Also refer this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder). It would get you started.

Comment: @FakhreldinMohamed Do you want any more information for it ?

Comment: Yes, please  @SaurabhLodha

Comment: You would have to be specific where you are facing any issue. The google places gem is good start to access the google places api. You need to create https://console.developers.google.com