# How to get a specific place in rails with Google Maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, maps

I have been trying to get a specific place in Rails with Google Maps, because when I try to get a restaurant, an university, I can't get! I only get the city, or the state, maybe the street, but not the place.

**view:**

```
<div style='width: 100%;' class="border">
  <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 260px;'></div>
</div>

<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAqkiGaIZh9q6DPUabw9E1rEqIQ-9X5amI"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
    <script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/printercu/google-maps-utility-library-v3-read-only/master/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script> <!-- only if you need custom infoboxes -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(15);
    });
    </script>
```

**Controller, action show:**

```
def show
   @enterprise = Enterprise.find(params[:id])
   @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@enterprise) do |enterprise, marker|
    marker.lat enterprise.latitude
    marker.lng enterprise.longitude
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe you need to use google place search API for this. have look at the docs https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: Is there any way to integrate goople places api to geocoder and googlemaps4rails?

Comment: Read answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073847/using-google-places-api-in-rails-app)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I need to add something like this in my app, I think in my javascript code, but I don't get any change

```
"results" : [
    {
      "place_id" : "MY_KEY_API",
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "alt_ids" : [
        {
          "place_id" : "MY_KEY_API",
          "scope" : "APP",
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide coordinates more accurate. Check enterprice latitude and longitude.

For example, not accurate will be

```
enterprise.latitude
# => 41
enterprise.longitude
# => -87
```

And accurate one are

```
enterprise.latitude
# => 41.850033
enterprise.longitude
# => -87.6500523
```

Comment: I have it as the second, maybe I need the place API

Comment: Describe defenetly what you want, please? Do you want to provide coordinates and get information about place?

Comment: Basically I need to get exact places, not in the streets, I want places like universities, restaurants, schools, etc. And I can not get it, it only manages to get the city, maybe the street of the place, but not the exact place that I show it marked

Answer (score 0):

i assume you need to be more specific while querying to google map...

so while using Google Places api..every [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_results)  object can query from various parameters...what you need is to specify `types` parameter too.

Copy and pasting from the above url...

```
types An array of types for this place (e.g., ["political", "locality"] or ["restaurant", "lodging"]).
```

Give it a try.. :)

Comment: Hi Milind! I'm not using Google Places, I'm just using Geocoder and GoogleMaps4Rails gems, when I come home I notice you about your suggest!